# Injectivity of the simple closed curves under geometric intersection number

Tags: geometric-group-theory, curves-and-surfaces, teichmuller-theory

Let $\Sigma$ be a closed surface of genus $g\geq 2$ and $\mathcal{C}$ be the set of  all free homotopy classes of simple closed curves in $\Sigma$. Define $i:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{\mathcal{C}}$ by $$i(x)(y)=i(x,y)$$ for $x,y\in \mathcal{C}$ where $i(x,y)$ is the geometric intersection number.

**Q) Does there exist a finite subset $K\subset\mathcal{C}$ such that $i:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow R^{K}$ is injective?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a collection of $9g - 9$ curves that suffices.  See Expose Six and Appendix C of "Thurston’s Work on Surfaces" edited by Fathi, Laudenbach, and Poenaru.

---

Here is a very short sketch - the details are complicated.  Suppose that $\Sigma$ is the given surface of genus $g$.  Let $P = \{\gamma_i\}$ be a pants decomposition of $\Sigma$.  We first recall the *Fenchel–Nielsen coordinates*.  Suppose that $\sigma$ is a hyperbolic metric on $\Sigma$.  For every $\gamma_i \in P$ we then have

- a hyperbolic length $\rm{len}(\gamma_i, \sigma)$ and
- a twist parameter $\rm{tw}(\gamma_i, \sigma)$.

The former is a positive real number and the second is a signed real number.  Care must be taken to understand the twist as a signed real number and not just as a circle valued number. We can recover the twist from length data as follows.  For each $i$, pick *dual* curves $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ so that the triple of curves $\{\alpha_i, \beta_i, \gamma_i\}$ meet each other non-trivially and minimally, and meet the rest of $P$ minimally.  Then the lengths of these $9g - 9$ curves recover the twist parameters.

We now can discuss the original question.  Again we have $\Sigma$ and $P$.  We now recall the *Dehn-Thurston coordinates*.  Suppose that $\delta$ is a simple closed curve.  For every $\gamma_i \in P$ we then have

- an intersection number $\rm{i}(\gamma_i, \delta)$ and
- a twist parameter $\rm{tw}(\gamma_i, \delta)$.

The former is a non-negative integer and the second is an integer.  Care must be taken to understand the twist.  It can be defined using from intersection data with dual curves, chosen as above.

Comment: I am considering the map from simple closed curves. $9g-9$ theorem is valid for the map from Teichmuller space. Am I missing something?

Comment: @tessellation Yes it applies. You might also be interested in Bonohan's paper on geodesic currents

Comment: @PaulPlummer Thanks for the confirmation. I was actually reading Bonohan's paper. I guess I am missing something.